# Expanding $\log[f(x)]$ as polynomials in perturbative method

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

In a homework question, we were asked to find the first order perturbation correction to $f(x)$ of the function defined by
$$f'(x)-f(x)=\epsilon\log(f(x))$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. The boundary condition is $f(0)=1$.

In the solution, $\log[f(x)]$ were expanded as a polynomial series (which in this case I assume to be the Maclaurin series) giving:
$$\log(f(x))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n f^n.$$

It is known that $\log(x)$ cannot be expanded around $x=0$, it looks like the solution expanded it around $f(x)=0$.

f(x) was also expanded in ε.
$$f=f_0+\epsilon f_1+\epsilon^2 f_2 ...$$
Thus
$$f'_0+\epsilon f'_1-f_0-\epsilon f_1 =\epsilon\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (f_0+\epsilon f_1 ...)^n$$
$$ f'_1- f_1 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (f_0)^n$$
Is the solution correct?

Comment: f was expanded in ε as well. I will edit my question.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Note that $\sum a_n f_0^n = \log(f_0)$ by the definition above (of the expansion of $\log f$) so you end up with $f_1' - f_1 = x$. which can be solved with the IC $f_1(0) = 0$ (since we require $f_0 + \epsilon f_1 = 1$ at $x=0$ and $f_0(0) = 1$ from the previous step).